# AngularJS : How to change the ng-show condition of a span using a java script function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to change the ng-show condition using a java script function.

```
<span id="error1" ng-show="formerror"><font color="red">{{formerror}}</font></span>
```

I'm able to get the span attr using

```
var scope4 = angular.element($("#error1"))
```

Comment: You want to change condition from outside of the Angular app?

Comment: @dfsq Yes, I'm using this in bootstrap modal and I have to make this condition false while hiding the model (on 'hidden.bs.modal' event).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it, however I doubt this is very good idea to manipulate with internals of the Angular app from outside of it. But it's possible.

You don't need attribute, you just need to access the scope of the element and change `formerror` property of it. You can do it using `scope` method of the `angular.element`. For example:

```
var $scope = angular.element($("#error1")).scope();
$scope.formerror = 'Fill in required fields.';
$scope.$apply();
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/cmiQCgnxbvG4hrGY1c18?p=preview

Comment: Thanks dfsq. Can I directly set the ng-show value to false?

Comment: You mean "true"? Yes, like this http://plnkr.co/edit/iyw30hy8Y5T3w8yuVrKL?p=preview. But if you want to set attribute value it's also possible, but I would avoid it, it required node recompiling. But possible.